# How can I delete JsonObject's main(root node's) name

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

Dunno how can I explain it I searched 9hr and finally need help.

`{"session_permit":{ "sessionID":"sessionID", "participantID":0, "timestamp":0, "signature":"somethinglongstring" }}`

this is what I made and I don't need "session_permit".

What I need is :

`{ "sessionID":"sessionID", "participantID":0, "timestamp":0, "signature":"somethinglongstring" }`

I finished delete "namevaluepairs" data on JsonObject but couldn't delete the main name on it. I have to send data type : JsonObject to server and when I make it by JsonObject, "sessionID" always added.

I put this to send request on server.

```
interface TalkJoinCredentialsApiInterface
{
    @POST("Prod/channel/join/Test")
    @Headers("Content-type: application/json",
        "Accept: */*")
    fun joinCredentialData(
        @Body requestData : TalkJoinCredentialsRequestData
    ) : Call<TalkJoinCredentialsResponseData>
}
```

```
class TalkJoinCredentialsRequestData(
   var session_permit : JsonObject
)
```

```
var jsonObject = JsonObject()
jsonObject.addProperty("sessionID", session_permit.sessionID)
jsonObject.addProperty("participantID", session_permit.participantID)
jsonObject.addProperty("timestamp", session_permit.timestamp)
jsonObject.addProperty("signature", session_permit.signature)

var requestData = TalkJoinCredentialsRequestData(jsonObject)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you getting an object with the `session_permit` and trying to access the inner JSON, or are you trying to send that object? If you are trying to send it in the format you described, you should probably define `TalkJoinCredentialsRequestData` as `class TalkJoinCredentialsRequestData(val sessionID: String, val participantID: Int, val timestamp: Int, val signature: String)` so it is serialized the way you expect it to.

Comment: want to use JsonObject without ``session_permit``. I'm trying to send it to server. will it be better to send by splited argument?

Comment: hell yeah my question was super idot and you helped me that was the right way thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!! @MrMikimn

Comment: Consider upvoting my comment if you felt it helped you :)

Comment: how can I vote comment?! wanna gib you 10000upvoting!!! I'm almost new account so gonna find how to vote comment wait for me!

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer which you can upvote and accept

Comment: thankyou! and sadly I don't have permission of vote :qwq: but I pushed it! https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/773419252354383902/877477677148295239/unknown.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably define TalkJoinCredentialsRequestData as

```
class TalkJoinCredentialsRequestData(val sessionID: String, val participantID: Int, val timestamp: Int, val signature: String)
```

so it is serialized the way you expect it to.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this :

```
var newJson = json.session_permit
```

Comment: dunno what is this for. Is that for new JsonObject???